# How to return to from function that uses a while loop

Tags: bash

In the main body of my script, I have the following:

```
while   read -p "Enter operand: " first
        checkRecall
...
```

where `checkRecall` is defined as:

```
checkRecall() {
    if [ "$next" = MR -a "$times" -ne 0 ]; then
        next=$MS
        echo "M -> $MS"
    elif [ "$first" = MR -a "$times" -eq 0 ]; then
        while   [ "$first" = MR ] # <-- PROBLEM: exits script when no longer true
        do
            echo "Nothing in memory"
            read -p "Enter a different operand: " first
        done
    fi
}
```

`times` is a variable that is incremented in the main body of the script.

I'm trying to return control flow back to the main body of the script when the condition `[ "$first" = MR -a "$times" -eq 0 ]` is no longer true. Instead, it exits out of my script. How do I achieve this?

Instead of `while   [ "$first" = MR -a "$times" -eq 0 ]`, I've tried using an `if/else` statement with `return`:

```
 while    if [ "$first" != MR ]; then
              return 1
          fi
          [ "$first" = MR ]
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Impossible to give you an answer: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `exit` exits the script, `return` returns from the function.

Comment: I don't see how the function can cause the script to exit since the function does not have any `exit` commands; at this point I'd have to assume there's an issue with the main script (but that's hard to tell since we don't have a complete, functioning example of your main script); and fwiw ... I ran the function through a simple `while` loop and after exercising all of the paths through the function I had no instances of 'exits' from the `while` loop (which, again, seems to imply a possible problem with the main script)

Comment: Do you have an exit-on-error option set in this script (`set -e` or something like that)? Those can trigger an exit for things you don't normally think of as an error.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the rest of the main script and don't see anything that would cause it to exit prematurely. It's likely I've missed something or there's a misunderstanding on my part somewhere but FWIW I was able to come up with a solution for now:

```
while   [ "$first" = MR ]
        do
            echo "Nothing in memory"
            read -p "Enter a different operand: " first
            if [ $first != MR ]; then return
            fi
        done
```